# Odd CSS Transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions

WHen ever I try and create a transition, the styles fade in to the elements, not just when hovered(an example). I really don't know what the issue is, and don't know where to start looking to fix this.

Example:

```
input[type='text'] {
    transition:.15s all;
    -webkit-transition:.15s all;
    -moz-transition:.15s all;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #545454;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

The size, expands when I load the page, along with the border. Any ideas on what the issue is?

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in http://jsfiddle.net? In what browser are you having this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, that you set the transition as default.
If you do it like this:

```
input[type='text'] {
   border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
   border-radius: 5px;
   color: #545454;
   font-size: 15px;
   padding: 4px;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
}

input[type='text']:hover {
   transition:.15s all;
   -webkit-transition:.15s all;
   -moz-transition:.15s all;
   font-size: 17px;
   color: black;
}
```

It will only active the transition if you hover the input.